# How to change the mysql queries to postgresql query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

When I execute the mysql query in postgresql it is showing the error .I have searched in google about the error but they are not working for me.Please suggest me to solve.

below is the mysql query:

```
SELECT caller_id_number,
       caller_id_name,
       dialed_number,
       count(*) NumberOfCalls,
       round(sum(duration_seconds)/60,2) CallDurationMin
FROM kazoo_cdr_rpt
WHERE cdr_date_time > '20-08-2017'
    AND cdr_date_time < 24-08-2017
    AND length(caller_id_number) < 5
    AND direction = "outbound"
GROUP BY dialed_number;
```

when I execute above query in postgres it is getting the error as

> ```
>  round(sum(durati...
>                                                              ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Comment: And what is your exact problem? Postgre is not MySQL so you can't queries expect to work. The error message is telling you why: A function you are using is not defined in Postgre, so check for your MySQL functions what the Postgre equivalents are.

Comment: can you suggest what is the function to be used at round(sum(duration_seconds)/60,2) to work in postgresql

Comment: your error looks odd - could you please copy/paste the whole text of exception?..

Comment: ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist

Comment: And what type is duration_seconds?

Comment: duration_seconds is VARCHAR

Comment: double quotes "outbound" will also fail, you need single quotes: 'outbound'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your duration second is `varchar`, you'll have to convert it to a number:

```
SELECT caller_id_number,
       caller_id_name,
       dialed_number,
       count(*) NumberOfCalls,
       round(sum(CAST(duration_seconds as numeric))/60,2) CallDurationMin
FROM kazoo_cdr_rpt
WHERE cdr_date_time > '20-08-2017'
    AND cdr_date_time < '24-08-2017'
    AND length(caller_id_number) < 5
    AND direction = "outbound"
GROUP BY caller_id_number, caller_id_name, dialed_number;
```

Comment: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 5:        round(sum(CAST(duration_seconds as float))/60,2) Call..

Comment: I am getting the above error when I execute your query

Comment: Sorry, wrong cast. I corrected my answer. `cast(... as numeric)` instead of float.

Comment: I am getting the below error after executing your query ERROR:  column "kazoo_cdr_rpt.caller_id_number" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: did you try to add it to the group by part? (adjusted answer)

Comment: why we need to add we need to group by dialed_numer column only.If I execute with GROUP BY caller_id_number, caller_id_name, dialed_number;result is different for MYsql and Postgresql

Comment: If you want to group by `dialed_number` only, you have to remove the fields `caller_id_number` and `caller_id_name` from the select part. The reason for this is simple. Imagine two different people call the same number and you group on this dialled number. Which name should be in the result?